# How to save entities across two databases in Laravel (Backpack)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, mongodb, laravel-backpack

I am new with Laravel and of course also with backpack.
I am using laravel 7.x and backpack 4.1 with both MySql and MongoDb.
The situation I am facing is that I have a company model with some attributes which are in MySql (both save and update working great with for the attributes stored in MySql) and other attributes that should be stored in MongoDb.
I have a CompanyPropertyCollection model for the attributes which I want to be stored in MongoDb
All these company will have a variable number of other arbitrary properties, which I want to save in mongo.
These properties may be simple scalar values or more complex values too (think arrays of objects), hence the idea to save them in mongo.

MySql Company table: [image]

My question is the following:
What is the best practice to save attributes of an entity in two distinct databases from BackPack? I override the CreateOperation, UpdateOperation with the store() and update() functions something like this:
Company model:

```
class Company extends Model
{
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Models\Traits\CrudTrait;
    use SoftDeletes;

    use HybridRelations;

    protected $connection = 'mysql';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'company_type',
        'is_active',
        'package_id',
        'certification_id',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'id' => 'integer',
        'is_active' => 'boolean',
        'package_id' => 'integer',
        'certification_id' => 'integer',
    ];

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
     */
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(\App\Models\User::class);
    }

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
     */
    public function package()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\Models\Package::class);
    }

    public function certification()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(\App\Models\Certification::class);
    }

    public function properties()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(\App\Models\CompanyPropertyCollection::class);
    }
}
```

CompanyPropertyCollection model:

```
class CompanyPropertyCollection extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $connection = 'mongodb';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        //'company_id',
        'email',
        'big_news_id',
        'phone.number',
        'phone.country_prefix',
        'phone.area_prefix',
        'phone.postfix',
        'year_of_foundation',
        'nr_of_employees',
        'nr_of_branches',
        'company_size',
        'subtitle',
        'homepage',
        'country_code',
        'city',
        'street',
        'post_code',
        'uid_nr',
        'registration_nr',
        'total_sales_area',
        'total_annual_bisuness_volume',
        'short_portrait',
        'long_portrait',
        'embedded_video',
        'certificates',
        'gallery',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'id' => 'integer',
        'gallery' => 'array',
    ];

    public function company()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\Models\Company::class);
    }
}
```

CompanyCrudController :

```
public function update()
{
    //$this->update( $company->properties);

    $response = $this->traitUpdate();
    // do something after save

    //use registered observer

    return $response;
}
```

Currently I am trying to use a CompanyObserver and on saving to store the data for mongo from the Request.

```
class CompanyObserver {

    public function saving(Company $company)
    {
        //dd(request()->request);
        $request = request()->request;

        dd($company->properties());

        //save to MongoDb
        dd('saving methond on the observer');
    }
}
```

Comment: "What is the best practice to save attributes of an entity in two distinct databases..."  Honest opinion, dont. Can you tell us why this is needed?

Comment: Are you getting an error or running into an issue, or does it work and you're just asking if there are any best practice that say you should do this a different way?

Comment: Having to pull attributes for a single "thing" from 2 different databases (of differing types) sounds like it'd be difficult to work with, 2 different but related models I could see, but the same model? But maybe Im misunderstanding?

Comment: @WesleySmith I added some more details to the question

Comment: Are you getting an error or running into an issue, or does it work and you're just asking if there are any best practice that say you should do this a different way?

Comment: It does not fully work yet, because I am not sure where/how to include the code that will save the things in mongo, after the save is done in mysql. This is why I am asking what is considered best practice in this case.

Comment: Like Wesley said, first of all, I’d avoid it if possible  However, it might actually be a GREAT idea, if an SQL model works well with a Mongo model, in Laravel. What I mean by this is that if you had a Company model (like now, using SQL) and instead of extending it you’d have a CompanyDetails model ($connection=mongodb), with a 1-1 relationship between them, then... in theory... they should work flawlessly together. No need to overwrite anything.

Comment: If that works well in Laravel, it’ll work well in Backpack too. You’d have two models, connected, one uses SQL one uses MongoDB. In Backpack, for fields, columns etc the only thing you’d need to change is that the name of the field should also include the name of the relationship (ex: details.email).

Comment: I’m very curious if this works well. But I’m not sure, it depends on Laravel itself. Please let me know 

Comment: Might not have done the best job explaining. On mobile, let me know if something needs clarification.

Comment: Hi, @tabacitu, yes I managed to connect my models to save it in both DB. Unfortunately I need to use  both(MySql and Mongo) I know it seems tricky but it was necessary I hope it will work fine. With the fields I made a Helper to generate the fields from a config file that is also working fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to perform some action after saving a model, like saving some user data in another db with a different type. You can override the model's `save` method.

Inside your model, add a method like the below

```
public function save(array $options = array())
{
  if (parent::save($options)) {
      // Model has been saved in mysql, now save in mongoDB
  }
}
```